# Filtering inside `for` with pattern matching

Tags: scala, iterator, pattern-matching

I am reading a TSV file and using using something like this:

```
case class Entry(entryType: Int, value: Int)

def filterEntries(): Iterator[Entry] = {
  for {
    line <- scala.io.Source.fromFile("filename").getLines()
  } yield new Entry(line.split("\t").map(x => x.toInt))
}
```

Now I am both interested in filtering out entries whose `entryType` are set to 0 and ignoring lines with column count greater or lesser than 2 (that does not match the constructor). I was wondering if there's an idiomatic way to achieve this may be using pattern matching and `unapply` method in a companion object. The only thing I can think of is using `.filter` on the resulting iterator.

I will also accept solution not involving `for` loop but that returns `Iterator[Entry]`. They solutions must be tolerant to malformed inputs.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more state-of-arty:

```
package object liner {
  implicit class R(val sc: StringContext) {
    object r {
      def unapplySeq(s: String): Option[Seq[String]] = sc.parts.mkString.r unapplySeq s
    }
  }
}

package liner {

  case class Entry(entryType: Int, value: Int)

  object I {
    def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = util.Try(s.toInt).toOption
  }

  object Test extends App {
    def lines = List("1 2", "3", "", "  4  5  ", "junk", "0, 100000", "6 7 8")

    def entries = lines flatMap {
      case r"""\s*${I(i)}(\d+)\s+${I(j)}(\d+)\s*""" if i != 0 => Some(Entry(i, j))
      case __________________________________________________ => None
    }
    Console println entries
  }
}
```

Hopefully, the regex interpolator will make it into the standard distro soon, but this shows how easy it is to rig up.  Also hopefully, a scanf-style interpolator will allow easy extraction with `case f"$i%d"`.

I just started using the "elongated wildcard" in patterns to align the arrows.

There is a pupal or maybe larval regex macro:

https://github.com/som-snytt/regextractor

Comment: This is 2.11 only, right? No matching in string interpolators in 2.10 IIRC.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't agree that this is a good idea: The liner doesn't do compile-time checking, that its argument string makes sense (no subgroup enforcing, etc.). Also note that the `.*` should probably be `.*?` and even then you have the problem that you'll catch lines like: "10 10 10". This is probably not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @gzm0 It's 2.10 kosher.

Comment: So this is wrong: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#limitations :(

Comment: Serves me right for looking at SO during hulu commercials. :(  Corrected the regex and added the 3-int case. :)

Comment: @gzm0 That's interesting. Frankly, I only use 2.11 and have to check on 2.10. You're right, so much is in flux over the two releases, it's so hard to keep anything straight, let alone macros.

Comment: @gzm0 Added link to a macro which is not 1.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variables in the head of the for-comprehension and then use a guard:

edit: ensure length of array

```
for {
  line <- scala.io.Source.fromFile("filename").getLines()
  arr = line.split("\t").map(x => x.toInt)
  if arr.size == 2 && arr(0) != 0
} yield new Entry(arr(0), arr(1))
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Probably I wrote the demo code wrongly. Unfortunately the point is that the input file may contain different number of columns that does not match Entry constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side of a `<-` or `=` in a for-loop may be a fully-fledged pattern. So you may write this:

```
def filterEntries(): Iterator[Int] = for {
  line <- scala.io.Source.fromFile("filename").getLines()
  arr = line.split("\t").map(x => x.toInt)
  if arr.size == 2
  // now you may use pattern matching to extract the array
  Array(entryType, value) = arr
  if entryType == 0
} yield Entry(entryType, value)
```

Note that this solution will throw a `NumberFormatException` if a field is not convertible to an Int. If you do not want that, you'll have to encapsulate `x.toInt` with a `Try` and pattern match again.

Comment: This will not filter, but throw a `MatchError` when the `entryType` is not 0 or the line does not have exactly 2 entries.

Comment: if entryType != 0, right?  You don't have a unit test, do you. Rhetorical question. (Sorry, just teasing.  Don't intend to discourage helping on SO.)

Comment: Oh, indeed. This is actually a misread specification (filtering out != retrieving) :P but `Array(type, value)` should of course be `Array(entryType, value)`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using the following code:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success}

val lines = List(
  "1\t2",
  "1\t",
  "2",
  "hello",
  "1\t3"
)

case class Entry(val entryType: Int, val value: Int)
object Entry {
  def unapply(line: String) = {
    line.split("\t").map(x => Try(x.toInt)) match {
      case Array(Success(entryType: Int), Success(value: Int)) => Some(Entry(entryType, value))
      case _ =>
        println("Malformed line: " + line)
        None
    }
  }
}

for {
  line <- lines
  entryOption = Entry.unapply(line)
  if entryOption.isDefined
} yield entryOption.get
```